# Issue: ping6 using the old destination IPv6 address

Tags: networking, ipv6, ubuntu-16.04

**Context:**

- My DNS cache is disabled at the client side
- Ping6 using DNS to resolve IPv6 addresses
- Server is multi-homed with 2 upstream service providers i.e. two prefixes
- I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

**Issue:**

Let's say we have a net1.example.com, and net2.example.com attached to the same server who DNS addresses can be obtained from the client. Client runs the following command

**ping6 net1.example.com**

and it pings the server using the provided IPv6 server address. But when I run

**ping6 net2.example.com**

it uses the older IPv6 address to echo.

Remember there is no caching at the client at all (nscd, named, systemd-resolvd, dnsmasq etc all off).

If I restart the system, and then I switch the above commands sequence, it follows the same thing i.e. it uses the first commands' obtained IPv6 addresses everytime I call ping6 with the other sub-domain name.

Any ideas why might it be doing like this? It happens if I use the curl etc as well.

Cheers,
K.

Comment: Time to look at your DNS resolver.

Comment: Give the true names involved.